# pass string with gaps in MakeFile

Tags: unix, makefile

I would like to pass a string with spaces as an argument in a Makefile.

For example:

```
make git msg="My message"
```

```
git:
    git commit -m $(msg)
```

I tried the symbols (", ') etc. but it didn't work.
I get the message :

> pathspec 'message' did not match any file(s) known to git

Comment: What shell command do you want Make to invoke, and what do you see it invoke in the output? I'll take a wild guess: you want `git commit -m "My message"` and you're getting `git commit -m My message`, am I right?

Comment: To debug such `make` intricacies, use `$(info $(_varname_))` to know precisely what is the contents of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape things when you send them to the shell.

As *always* when writing makefile recipes the first step is to run the command at the shell prompt.  If it doesn't work from the shell prompt, it definitely won't work in a makefile!  If you run this at your shell prompt:

```
git command -m My message
```

you'll see you get that same error.  What do you have to do to make that error go away?  You have to quote the message, like this:

```
git command -m 'My message'
```

(or you can use double-quotes in this situation but in general single quotes are safer if you don't need double-quotes).

So, change your makefile to suite:

```
git:
        git commit -m '$(msg)'
```

Comment: You must add single quote on the command (make git msg='My Message') and inside the makefile (git commit -m '$(msg)')